# fvm flutter run Android Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file

Tags: android, flutter

I got the following error when running:

```
fvm flutter run
```

And got this error:

```
Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 50.
```

FVM use Flutter version 3.0.5

I have been doing this but also failed to fix the problem:

1. Delete the user folder's .gradle file
2. Delete the project .gradle file
3. Use Android Studio to open my Flutter Android Project

After searching the internet, still not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue. The issue cause is the problem on the gradle files / broken gradle files.

Deleting the original location of the gradle is not helpful. Then an alternative is to move the gradle files location:

simple add this to `android/gradlew.bat` to indicate the gradle download location to a new location, for example, D drive instead or the default location
`set GRADLE_OPTS="-Dgradle.user.home=D:/Android/gradle"`

So part of the file becomes:

```
....

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%
set GRADLE_OPTS="-Dgradle.user.home=D:/Android/gradle"

...
```